# Postgres: copy value of specific field from referenced table only for matching foreign keys

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have two tables in the same postgres database:

EntityA:

| Column | type | nullable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | uuid | false |
| value1 | varchar | true |
| value2 | varchar | true |
| entityB_id | foreign key | true |

EntityB:

| Column | type | nullable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | uuid | false |
| value1 | varchar | true |
| value2 | varchar | true |

I know need to copy the value1 and value2 from the EntityB table into the table of EntityA, but only for the lines where the EntityB id is referenced.

I tried the following without success:

```
insert into EntityA (value1, value2)
select EntityB.value1, EntityB.value2 
from EntityB
where EntityA.entityB_id = EntityB.id
```

I found other guides on how to copy data from one table to another, however not with a condition has to be met. I am currently at a loss on how to successfully copy that data. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by copy? Do you want to update the original row? In your query it looks like you want to duplicate rows that have a relation while loosing the relation on new rows.

Comment: I want to copy the values of EntityB.value1 to EntityB.value1 and from EntityB.value2 to EntityB.value2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to update data in table A using data that is stored in B. e.g. you start with

| A | id | value1 | value2 | entityB_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | null | null | 2 |

| B | id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2 | 'test' | 'test2' |

And expect the following result in A:

| A | id | value1 | value2 | entityB_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | 'test' | 'test2' | 2 |

Instead of `INSERT` you need to use `UPDATE` as you want to modify existing rows:

```
UPDATE "EntityA" a
SET value1 = (
    SELECT b."value1"
    FROM "EntityB" b
    WHERE b.id = a."entityB_id"
),
value2 = (
    SELECT b."value2"
    FROM "EntityB" b
    WHERE b.id = a."entityB_id"
)
WHERE "entityB_id" IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This can be done with only one sub-query: https://pastebin.com/0bmLTwjT

Comment: Can confirm: solution of @a_horse_with_no_name works as well!